# No rule to make target 'openmp'?

Tags: makefile, openmp, compiler-flags

The following is defined in the makefile:

```
CXX = g++
CXXFLAGS = -std=c++11
```

I would like to compile my code with OpenMP directives without changing the original makefile (which runs perfectly). The manual suggests a way to do this, is by changing it on the command line. However, when I run,

```
 make CXXFLAGS=-std=c++11 -fopenmp
```

the error mentioned before pops up. Can someone help me understand what I'm doing wrong?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The problem here is the space between `-std=c++11` and `-fopenmp`. It splits these two arguments up and the `-fopenmp` is interpreted as the option `-f` then `openmp` is interpreted as a `makefile` that `make` attempts to build because it can't find it in the current directory.

You need to execute `make` with quotes (`"`) like

```console
$ make CXXFLAGS="-std=c++11 -fopenmp"
```

this will pass `CXXFLAGS= -std=c++11 -fopenmp` to `make`. We can see this behaviour with the following simple `makefile`.

```
CXX = g++
CXXFLAGS = -std=c++11

all:
    @echo $(CXXFLAGS)
```

Running `make` will produce the output

```console
$ make
-std=c++11
```

Running `make CXXFLAGS="-std=c++11 -fopenmp"` will produce

```console
$ make
-std=c++11 -fopenmp
```

the correct output and what we were hoping to achieve.

---

As an aside the command, `make CXXFLAGS= -std=c++11 -fopenmp`, in your question should produce more errors than just

```console
make: openmp: No such file or directory
make: *** No rule to make target 'openmp'.  Stop.
```

because of the space between `CXXFLAGS=` and `-std=c++11`. I get

```console
$ make CXXFLAGS= -std=c++11 -fopenmp
make: invalid option -- =
make: invalid option -- c
make: invalid option -- +
make: invalid option -- +
make: invalid option -- 1
make: invalid option -- 1
```

If for instance you want to compile with `-std=c++14` instead of `-std=c++11` you would need to execute `make` with

```console
$ make CXXFLAGS=-std=c++14
```

**note**: *no space*, or equivalently with

```console
$ make CXXFLAGS="-std=c++14"
```

again without a space.

Comment: Thank you! Writing it as a string works perfectly! The space after CXXFLAGS in the question was a typo and I've corrected it! :)

Comment: No bother, glad to help.

Answer (score 1):

Space - The Final Frontier. You need quotes as in

```
make CXXFLAGS="-std=c++11 -fopenmp"
```

The shell splits command line words at word boundaries delimited by white space. Quoting is used to avoid word-splitting.