# R installation of package `later` fails

Tags: c++, r, rcpp

Software info:

- Linux Kernel: 4.14.83-1-MANJARO
- R: 3.5.1
- Rcpp: 1.0.0
- g++ g++ (GCC) 8.2.1 20180831

I'm trying to install the `later` package from CRAN, but it fails due to a compilation error and I can't figure out whether there is something wrong with my own configuration or the package. The installation stops after the call

`g++  -I"/usr/include/R/" -DNDEBUG -pthread -DTHREADS_H_SUPPORT=1 -I"/home/karpfen/R-libs/Rcpp/include" -I"/usr/lib/R/library/BH/include" -D_FORTIFY_SOURCE=2  -fopenmp -fpic  -march=x86-64 -mtune=generic -O2 -pipe -fstack-protector-strong -fno-plt  -c timestamp_win32.cpp -o timestamp_win32.o`

with the error message

> make: *** No rule to make target '-fopenmp', needed by 'later.so'.  Stop.

`Rcpp` and other packages depending on it work as expected. Is there anything that I could be doing wrong here? I tried reinstalling R + packages already, but no changes here.

Edit:

The first few lines of the installation output are

```
* installing *source* package ‘later’ ...
** package ‘later’ successfully unpacked and MD5 sums checked
Running configure script
Using CC=gcc
Using CFLAGS=-march=x86-64 -mtune=generic -O2 -pipe -fstack-protector-strong -fno-plt
Using CPPFLAGS=-D_FORTIFY_SOURCE=2
C11-style threads.h support detected.
```

Edit2:

System information (from `/etc/lsb-release`)

```
DISTRIB_ID=ManjaroLinux
DISTRIB_RELEASE=18.0.0
DISTRIB_CODENAME=Illyria
DISTRIB_DESCRIPTION="Manjaro Linux"
```

Comment: When installing the package, before it started compilation, it should have also should have had output like `Using CC=... Using CFLAGS=...
Using CPPFLAGS=...`. What did that part say?

Comment: Thanks for the hint, I added it to the question.

Comment: Well, something on _your system_ (that you told us little about: what distro is it?) and the assumption of the `later` author do not mesh.  But `-fopenmp` is never a `make` target, it is typically something filled in by R itself based on its compile-time settings -- your can grep R's own `Makeconf` for it.

Comment: @DirkEddelbuettel is right, you should put what system you're using; I happened to catch that it's Manjaro, but you should make that explicit (and mention which edition you've got). It might be related to [this Stack Overflow post](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/32233074/no-rule-to-make-target-openmp)

Comment: Nice catch by @duckmayr.  Looks like the flags get built the wrong way. You may get by editing either `configure` or `src/Makevars.in`, and you may to raise an issue [here](https://github.com/r-lib/later).

Comment: Thanks for the pointers, I'll try and see if I can get it to run now. I added the distribution info as well.

Comment: Oddly my Ubuntu box gets `C11-style threads.h support not detected. Using tinycthread library.` but it all builds and installs (and `-DBOOST_NO_AUTO_PTR` in `~/.R/Makevars` helps quieten it).

Comment: Nice, disabling the line `$(SHLIB): @libs@` in `Makevars.in` worked for me. Although I hope this won't break anything further down the line. Thanks so much!

Comment: @DirkEddelbuettel Same on m Debian testing machine. According to https://stackoverflow.com/questions/22875545/c11-gcc-threads-h-not-found C11 style threading is only available with glibc 2.28, which is only in Debian unstable. I wonder why threading from *C11* instead of *C++11* is used.

Comment: @karpfem If I were you I'd spend the extra ten minutes trying to make it work, and then see what causes it: _either_ you distro R build brings a bad value from its `Makeconf`, or `later` does something bad.  But the `configure` script in `later` is so minimal that I can basically rule that out.  In short, try to make a working version "by hand", infer where the system failed.  None of us seem to have the C11 threads library so we cannot replicate.

Comment: Oh, you didn't tell us you already filed it:  https://github.com/r-lib/later/issues/71 See also https://github.com/r-lib/later/issues/77 there -- it is being contemplated to make the build simpler.  I think it is becoming clearer that your error comes from your distro.  Examine your `Makeconf` for its flags.