# Build Docker Image from Alpine with 'later' R-package

Tags: r, docker, shiny

When I try build an image from the following Dockerfile, it fails. (I am using Portainer, it simply shows "build failed" with no further explanation.)

```
FROM rhub/r-minimal:4.0.5

RUN apk update

RUN installr -d -t "R-dev file linux-headers libxml2-dev gnutls-dev openssl-dev libsass-dev libx11-dev cairo-dev libxt-dev libuv-dev geos-dev gdal-dev proj-dev sqlite-dev cmark-dev http-parser-dev" \ 
    -a "libxml2 libuv cmark libgit2 openssl cairo libsass libx11 font-xfree86-type1 sqlite proj gdal geos http-parser" later

RUN rm -rf /var/cache/apk/*

RUN addgroup --system app && adduser --system --ingroup app app
```

I am trying to build an image for shiny/leaflet and this package seems to be responsible for not getting there...

I also tried [the r-hub/r-minimal example](https://github.com/r-hub/r-minimal/blob/master/examples/shiny/Dockerfile) but it failed too.

I am aware of [this discussion](https://stackoverflow.com/q/53558095/216064) but can not act on it.

Interestingly, the following Dockerfile works:

```
FROM rhub/r-minimal:4.0.5

RUN apk update

RUN installr -d -t "R-dev file linux-headers libsodium-dev" \ 
    -a "libsodium font-xfree86-type1" later

RUN rm -rf /var/cache/apk/*

RUN addgroup --system app && adduser --system --ingroup app app
```

Any ideas on how to get a small Docker image for shiny/leaflet is very appreciated.